# How to set the image for UINavigation bar which is supported from 3.2 version

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I am new to iphone.I have a small doubt that is How can we set the background image of navigation bar.If in the later versions there is an api for setbackgroundimage but my application wants to support it from version 3.2 so this api is not useful for me .So, how can i place an image to the navigation bar.If any body know this please help me...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show custom view as Navigation bar you can do following steps:

1) Hide Navigation bar

2) Put ur custom view on top 
Or
Instead of putting custom views in xib (If you have lots of xibs) then create custom VC and use it as super view for each VC in your project so that it will inherit automatically.